# Do async script tags get loaded before blocking script tags in the body of an html document?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I have a client rendered react app.

Let's say I have some other 3rd party javascript that is loaded like so:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="root"><!-- app gets loaded herer --></div>
    <script async src='https://cdn.third-party.com/segment.js'></script>
    <script async src='https://cdn.third-party.com/google_analytics.js'></script>

    <script src='https://example.com/mybundle.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`mybundle.js` contains the actual React app that gets rendered inside of the root tag.

Do the 3rd party scripts `segment.js` and `google_analytics.js` affect the load time of `mybundle.js`? Do they get downloaded and parsed before `mybundle.js`? Will they slow down rendering of my app?

Comment: They will affect the load time (because they are written before) but in a trivial way. the computer has to read those lines which technically takes time. i know, specific answer, but this is StackOverflow. why are you using async? it looks like they have local paths. Since they are local, they will probably load before mybundle.js. 

you could always write a console.log in each in see which prints first

Comment: They are 3rd party external scripts. Will they get downloaded and parsed before mybundle does?